# jQuery draggable with zoom and grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, zooming, draggable

I'm trying to add a grid for my jQuery draggable div when in zoom mode.
The functions `startFix()` and `dragFix()` solves the position problem for the zoom and works very good. However, grid doesn't work here.

Can I add grid somehow manually?

```js
function startFix(evt, ui) {
  var zoom = $('#wrap').css('zoom');
  pointerY = (evt.pageY - $('#wrap').offset().top) / zoom - parseInt($(evt.target).css('top'));
  pointerX = (evt.pageX - $('#wrap').offset().left) / zoom - parseInt($(evt.target).css('left'));
}

function dragFix(evt, ui) {
  var zoom = $('#wrap').css('zoom');
  var canvasTop = $('#wrap').offset().top;
  var canvasLeft = $('#wrap').offset().left;
  var canvasHeight = $('#wrap').height();
  var canvasWidth = $('#wrap').width();

  // Fix for zoom
  ui.position.top = Math.round((evt.pageY - canvasTop) / zoom - pointerY);
  ui.position.left = Math.round((evt.pageX - canvasLeft) / zoom - pointerX);

  // Finally, make sure offset aligns with position
  ui.offset.top = Math.round(ui.position.top + canvasTop);
  ui.offset.left = Math.round(ui.position.left + canvasLeft);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#drag').draggable({
    start: startFix,
    drag: dragFix,
    grid: [50, 50] // not working when using startfix and dragfix
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #FFF;
}

div#wrap {
  background: #C00;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden
}

div#drag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #CCC;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap" style="zoom:150%">
  <div id="drag">Drag me</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/centrumkanalen/pen/jOEGjwY

Comment: Please clarify *grid doesn't work here*. I suspect you need to adjust the gris in your `startFix` . Otherwise you may need to make your own custom grid function in `drag`

Comment: When I test in your codepen, it does not work at all.

Comment: Also `zoom` is a nonstandard property and not supported by modern browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom Seems only supported by Safari.

Comment: Basically everyone except Firefox. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom
This is a webapp where users only use Chrome